# Associate events by transaction across multiple contracts

Tags: evm

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. ContractA has a method that creates EventA
2. ContractB has a method that creates EventB
3. User submits a transaction the touches both event-generating methods on ContractA and ContractB. So, now we have a single transaction the generated two events.

I'd like to be able to include a topic in those events that somehow identifies the transaction. I have been following https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/901, which discusses my ideal solution: add `tx.hash` to the EVM global variables. But this doesn't look like it will happen anytime soon.

The reason I'd like to associate the events by transaction in the events, is because my downstream system is a kind of side-network that materializes these events in a structured way. Of course, anyone could come along and list the events from ContractA and ContractB, and create this association manually (ie, all the data is there as read externally), but this flow won't work for my use case.

Save for this un-implemented `tx.hash`, is there any other way I might be able to create this association in the events? Maybe there is some other hash I could create from the available global variables + msg data? I have `block.number`, `txn.gasPrice`, etc., which is a start, but could create false positive associations.

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a bytes32 hashing the input parameters, and pass that parameter to both contracts.

Comment: Thanks Ismael, unfortunately in this case I don't have control over the sender. I just have control over what contracts they touch in their single transaction.